# Matrix multiplication makes zero to specific elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this matrix $A = \pmatrix{3&2&5\\ 1&2&3\\ 2&3&5\\ 1&3&4}$.
I want to multiply this matrix by another one, say $M$, **which must have its diagonal elements = 1**, and the result must be: $MA = \pmatrix{3&2&5\\ 1&0&3\\ 2&0&5\\ 1&0&4}$.

Should I multiply the inv(A)x(result_matrix) to get the matrix $M$ or is there any other procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yea but A does not have inverse

Answer (score 1):

Try a Moore Penrose inverse.  You can write

$$A=UDV',$$

where $U$ is orthogonal and contains the eigenvectors of $AA'$ corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues, $V$ is orthogonal and contains the eigenvectors of $A'A$ corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues, and $D$ is diagonal and contains the nonzero eigenvalues of $A'A$ as its diagonal elements.

Write $B$ for the matrix you have written as $MA$.  Then

$$MA=B \Rightarrow M=BV D^{-1} U',$$

and you're done!

Comment: >>[U,S,V] = svd(a)
>>b*V*inv(S)*U'
Error using inv
Matrix must be square.
b is the result matrix

Comment: So what it's done is pad out the matrix with zeroes, aaargh! Just take the bit that's diagonal, invert it, and pad it out with zeroes in the other direction (rows instead of columns or vice versa)

Comment: What software are you using?  Most software packages would contain routines to compute Moore Penrose inverses.

Comment: In Matlab it would be pinv